# Validating Variables in Shell Script

Tags: unix, shell, scripting

What is the best way to make sure that all the environment variables I need for my script have been set?
Currently, I have multiple if-statements which is not very neat:

```
if [ -z "$VAR1" ]
then
    echo VAR1 not set
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$VAR2" ]
then
    echo VAR2 not set
    exit
fi

if [ -z "$VAR3" ]
then
    echo VAR3 not set
    exit
fi
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indirection:

```
vars="FOO BAR"
for var in $vars
do
    [[ -z ${!var} ]] && 
        echo "Variable ${var} is empty" ||
        echo "The value of variable ${var} is ${!var}"
done
```

Comment: Exactly what i meant! Great!!+1

Comment: Note that this tests if empty, not if it is set

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop in (set of variables u want). Won't that work?

Comment: Thanks! I wont suggest this in future. I was also not sure. Just asked :)

Comment: plz edit your answer, I misunderstood it and erroneously downvoted. Edit in order to make me remove my vote

Comment: I would also use a for loop for this, helps cut down on repeating yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**you can short them a lot:**

```
[ -z "$FOO" ] && echo "FOO is empty"
[ -z "$BAR" ] && echo "BAR is empty"
```

**a better way:**

```
${FOO:?"FOO is null or not set"}
${BAR:?"BAR is null or not set"}
```

Of course if the number of variables you are going to test is not low, looping as suggested @Aviator maybe useful to avoid repeating code.

Upon @Aviator answer, I'd like to suggest to define a well commented variable containing a list of your variables-to-be-tested. This way you don't make your code cryptic.

> `TEST_FOR_IS_SET="FOO BAR BAZ"`

Answer (score 1):

I have this function in my shell library:

```
# Check that a list of variables are set to non-null values.
# $@: list of names of environment variables. These cannot be variables local
#     to the calling function, because this function cannot see them.
# Returns true if all the variables are non-null, false if any are null or unset
varsSet()
{
        local var
        for var ; do
                eval "[ -n \"\$$var\" ] || return 1"
        done
}
```

I use it in code like this:

```
varsSet VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 || <error handling here>
```